# Photos and Video's deleted from Nokia Storyteller

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

I have purchased a Lumia 535 a week ago, and yesterday I was going through an option called [Lumia Storyteller](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/lumia-storyteller/b0940143-e67e-4f74-8f68-16b7ad872dd2). Once I created a story based on the images, I deleted the images from Storyteller but unfortunately all my photos and videos from the Gallery are deleted too.

(Note : I Have not deleted photos from main folder, I have deleted only from Storyteller).

Is there any way to restore the photos and videos?

Comment: Have you looked in your OneDrive account as your photos, etc should be backed up there?

Comment: Thank you Thomas and Neil, One drive backup was off so thier was no backup. Now I have turned on to send backup.

Answer (score 1):

Photos in Storyteller are the same as those in your gallery - just displayed differently. So if you delete them in one app they'll be missing in the other one as well.

Check your OneDrive if your phone made a backup of your images there. Also if your pictures were saved on a microSD card you might be able to restore them using tools like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

Otherwise I'm afraid you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! Bad Luck.... Go to **Settings->Backup** and make your options. Storyteller is not different than our gallery.

I guess *One Drive* is ON by default for gallery items may be on your phone when you brought it.